# How to select first n items of list in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a list and i want to do an operation on first 3 items of list if they are not 0.i can do my operation on each item by code below,but dont know how to do it for first 3 items.

```
foreach list2
[
 if (item ? list2 != 0) 
  [
   set candidatelist lput (item ? list3) candidatelist
 ]
]
```

Comment: Why do both `list2` and `list3` appear here? Are those supposed to be the same?

Comment: they are not the same.list2 has frequency of list3 data in sequence.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a helper for getting the first n elements:

```
to-report take [n xs]
  report sublist xs 0 min list n (length xs)
end
```

Now we can write:

```
filter [x -> x != 0] take 3 ...
```

sample run:

```
observer> show filter [x -> x != 0] take 3 [1 0 3 4 5]
observer: [1 3]
```

(That's NetLogo 6 syntax. In NetLogo 5, write `[? != 0]` instead of `[x -> x != 0]`.)

Answer (score 1):

i wrote code below to solve it:

```
let m 0
 foreach list2
  [
   if (m < 3)
    [
     if (item ? list2 != 0) 
      [
       set candidatelist lput (item ? list3) candidatelist
        ]
     set m m + 1
       ]
     ]
```

Comment: I don't think this code does what you think it does. By `item ? list2`, I think you mean `item m list2` or simply `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if` and `item`

```
if (item x list != 0) and (item x+1 list != 0) and (item x+2 list != 0)
[
set item x list
set item x+1 list
set item x+2 list
]
```